Trying to find PowerPoint '98
I am looking for a PowerPoint '98 look-alike?
I looked through some basic google searches, but am not sure which are safe.
I am hoping to create a presentation with a retro feel and don't want to use a webapp, if possible.
An open-source alternative would be epic.

Welcome K_T. Most of your question is off-topic in our community, as we don't provide answers to "where to download/access xyz" here. And if PowerPoint '98 wasn't free, that would be a double no-no.  But an open-source alternative is definitely on-topic, so please edit your question to just ask for that.  Thanks for your understanding, and again, welcome!

It's unclear to me why you want PowerPoint '98. What's so special about this version. The obvious open source alternative is LibreOffice Impress or its predecessor OpenOffice. Do you know about them? Did you try them?

Ah yes, nice idea - thanks :)
